# Connection string 'SqlServer' not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `Net standard class library` which I use for both `windows forms` and `xamarin forms` app. I got some method there `GetConnectionString` which works perfectly in windosw forms and reads the config entry from `App.Config`, nevertheless when I tried to use the method in `xamarin android` project creating `App.config` there it seems it cannot be read somehow. From where when reached `return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString` will try to read the entry in xamarin android project?

**Exception:**

```
System.Exception: 'Connection string 'SqlServer' not found.'
```

**GetConnectionString**

```
 public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionName)
 {
        try
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
        }
            catch (Exception)
            {
              throw new Exception($"Connection string '{connectionName}' not found.");
            }
}
```

**App.config:**

```
<configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=mydb;User=sa;Password=abc;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you can't use the System.Configuration in Android or iOS

Comment: That's what *your* code throws. You don't know what the *actual* exception is. At the very least pass the original exception as an inner exception. Better yet, just *don't* catch that exception. I doubt you can use the application at all if you can't connect to the database

Comment: What should i do then?

Comment: Configure connection string as static readonly string somewhere to reuse it in your app..

Comment: @Adlorem what is most known approach to keep connection string for xamarin forms?

Comment: Most known approach is NOT to keep any connection strings inside your code, especially when this code is accessible and can be decompiled.  Most known approach is to use server api to get data you want.